# react cannot read properties of null of ref with forwardRef and useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I'm using function components. I am using `useRef` to store a `previousValueCount` because I don't want it to rerender the component when it updates. *This works perfect as long as my `useRef` declaration is in the component that my code reads and writes with that ref in*. However, realizing I may need this higher up the tree, I turned to props. However, when I moved the `useRef` declaration to the parent and passed the ref as a prop, the code seemed to break, telling me it was null, regardless of the initialization value and it working before in child. To my understanding I could not pass ref as prop so I turned to `React.forwardRef`. I tried the same thing with no solution and a similar error shared below. How can I pass a ref as a prop or down component tree?

APP COMPONENT:

```
function App() {
  const [itemsLeftCount, setItemsleftCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <ToDos
      itemsLeftCount={itemsLeftCount}
      setItemsLeftCount={setItemsLeftCount}
    ></ToDos>
  )
}
```

PARENT COMPONENT:

```
function ToDos(props) {
  const prevItemsLeftCountRef = useRef(0);

  return (
    <ToDoBox
      itemsLeftCount={props.itemsLeftCount}
      setItemsLeftCount={props.setItemsLeftCount}
      ref={prevItemsLeftCountRef}
    ></ToDoBox>

  {
```

CHILD COMPONENT:

```
const ToDoBox = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    //LINE 25 Error points to right below comment
    ref.prevItemsLeftCountRef.current = props.itemsLeftCount;
  }, [props.itemsLeftCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //ON MOUNT
    props.setItemsLeftCount(ref.prevItemsLeftCountRef.current + 1);

    //ON UNMOUNT
    return function removeToDoFromItemsLeft() {
      //this needs to only run after setitemsleftcount state is for sure done updating
      props.setItemsLeftCount(ref.prevItemsLeftCountRef.current - 1);
    };
  }, []);
})
```

I receive this error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'prevItemsLeftCountRef')
at ToDoBox.js:25:1**

@Mustafa Walid

```
function ToDos(props) {
  const prevItemsLeftCountRef = useRef(0);
  const setPrevItemsLeftCountRef = (val) => {
    prevItemsLeftCountRef.current = val;
  };

 return (
   <ToDoBox
     itemsLeftCount={props.itemsLeftCount}
     setItemsLeftCount={props.setItemsLeftCount}
     prevItemsLeftCountRef={prevItemsLeftCountRef}
     setPrevItemsLeftCountRef={setPrevItemsLeftCountRef}
    ></ToDoBox>
  )
}

function ToDoBox(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    //itemsLeftCount exists further up tree initialized at 0
    props.setPrevItemsLeftCountRef(props.itemsLeftCount); 
  }, [props.itemsLeftCount]);

}
```

Comment: `ref.prevItemsLeftCountRef.current` should be `ref.current`

Comment: Which version of react you're using?

Comment: @hackape this change gave this error: ToDoBox.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'current')

Comment: @monim version "^18.2.0"

Comment: check  **package.json** and change  version `"react": "18.x.x",`  to `"react": "^18.x.x",`

Comment: @monim it is already:  "react": "^18.x.x" as it is currently "react": "^18.2.0", unless you meant remove the carrot(^) from the version instead of suggesting I add it?

Comment: To directly answer your question React refs can either be passed as the special `ref` prop (*may need to be forwarded*) or as a regular old named prop. You seem to be really asking about something else though. As hackape points out, `ref.prevItemsLeftCountRef.current` should be `ref.current` as React refs ***only ever*** have a `.current` property to access. `ref.prevItemsLeftCountRef` can only ever be undefined. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-cannot-read-properties-of-null-of-ref-with-forwardref-and-useref-b55wwy) of your code with the ref access corrected.

Comment: OFC the code in the sandbox doesn't do anything because your code also doesn't do anything, it's a simple copy/paste with correction applied. What is that you are trying to accomplish with this code? Why are you not using regular React state?

Comment: @DrewReese I did not want to use state because I didn't want to force a rerender of the component when said state would update. That would case an infinite loop in my code causing ItemsLeft to incriment infinitely.

Comment: @DrewReese I will give your updates a chance when I have time today

Comment: ***Not*** using and updating a React state is far more likely to lead to rendering issues since React refs don't ever trigger a component to rerender. If using and updating a React state leading to render looping then you are not sufficiently conditionally updating the state.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks for sharing your knowledge, I think I dont understand how yet to condition my state in the way I need, I'll keep working at it!

Comment: What are you trying to do? This code is for a todo app, so it's not like there aren't a gazillion demos and tutorials out there. What is the issue when you use React state? This is starting to feel like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @DrewReese my goal from the start was to be able to store my data further up the tree. when I got it working at first with ref in the initial component I wanted to move the ref to exist up in app.js, as todobox just needs to be able to read the value and update itemsLeft when a todobox mounts or unmounts. I had difficulty obviously trying to pass the ref down and still work. When I implement this with state, it increments when I add boxes, and decrements when I delete boxes. Great. except the first time I ever delete a box, it decrements by 2, and then every one after that it decrements by 1?

Comment: @DrewReese using a ref made that issue go away. Im not sure why it decrements by an extra one value the first time any box unmounts and then decrements normal after every unmount after that. It doesnt matter what the decrement is, the first time you delete a box it will decrement itemsLeft by one more of that decrement, then every box delete after that decrements normal...

Comment: Sounds like there is an unintentional side-effect somewhere in the code. Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese give this a shot! hope it shared properly. https://codesandbox.io/embed/musing-goldberg-p32fqk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

as youll  notice, first time deleting a todo, the count does down by 2, then every delete after that only by 1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

You don't need a ref for any of this. You should be using React state. I really couldn't exactly nail down any one specific issue that causing the double initial decrement, but there are quite a few issues in the code that they are all worth mentioning.

## Solution

First, the mounting `useEffect` hook in the `ToDoBox` component. I see that you were trying to keep and maintain ***two*** item count state values, a current value and a previous value. This is completely redundant and as the code shows, can lead to state synchronization issues. Simply stated, you should be using a [functional state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) right here to correctly access the previous item count state value to increment or decrement it. You may want to also check that the current `ToDoBox` component isn't the "create box" in the returned clean up function, to ensure the `ToDoBox` that creates todos doesn't accidentally update the item count.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // RUNS ON MOUNT
  if (!isCreateBox) {
    setItemsLeftCount(count => count + 1);
  }
  
  return function removeToDoFromItemsLeft() {
    if (!isCreateBox) {
      setItemsLeftCount(count => count - 1);
    }
  };
}, []);
```

This alone was enough to stop the item count double-decrement issue.

## Other issues I noticed

### *State mutations*

Both the functions to add ***and*** delete todos are both mutating the state. This is why you had to add the auxiliary `state` state in `ToDos` to force your app to rerender and display the mutations.

#### `addToDoToList`

Here `updatedArr` is a reference to the `dataArr` state object/array, and the function pushes ***directly*** into the array (the mutation), and then saves the very same object/array reference back into state.

```
function addToDoToList() {
  let updatedArr = dataArr;   // <-- saved reference to state
  updatedArr.push(dataInput); // <-- mutation!!
  setDataArr(updatedArr);     // <-- same reference back into state
}
```

```
function handleClickCreateButton() {
  addToDoToList(); // <-- mutates state
  //force a rerender of todos
  setState({});    // <-- force rerender to see mutation
}
```

#### `handleClickDeleteButton`

Here, similarly, `updateArr` is a reference to the current state. `Array.prototype.splice` mutates the array in-place. And again, the mutated state reference is saved back into state and a force rerender is required.

```
function handleClickDeleteButton() {
  // if splice from dataArr that renders a component todobox for each piece of data
  // if remove data from dataArr, component removed...
  let updatedArr = dataArr;    // <-- saved reference to state
  updatedArr.splice(index, 1); // <-- mutation!!
  setDataArr(updatedArr);      // <-- same reference back into state

  // then need to rerender todos... I have "decoy state" to help with that
  setState({});
}
```

Oddly enough, the comments around this code implies you even know/understand that something is up.

The solution here is to *again* use functional state updates to correctly update from the previous state ***and*** return new object/array references at the same time so React sees that state has updated and triggers the rerender. I suggest also adding an `id` GUID to the todos to make identifying them easier. This is better than using the array index.

Examples:

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

...

function addTodo() {
  // concat to and return a new array reference
  setDataArr(data => data.concat({
    id: nanoid(),
    todo: dataInput,
  }));
}

function removeTodo(id) {
  // filter returns a new array reference
  setDataArr(data => data.filter(todo => todo.id !== id));
}
```

### Other General Design Problems

- Props drilling of the root `itemsLeftCount` state and `setItemsLeftCount` state updater function all the way down to the leaf `ToDoBox` components.
- Not centralizing the control over the `dataArr` state invariant.
- Using the mapped array index as the React key.
- Trying to compute "derived" state, i.e. the item count, in nested children.

Here's a boiled-down/minified working version of your code:

App

```
function App() {
  const [itemsLeftCount, setItemsLeftCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <ToDos setItemsLeftCount={setItemsLeftCount} />
      <div>{itemsLeftCount} items left</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ToDos

```
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

function ToDos({ setItemsLeftCount }) {
  const [dataInput, setInputData] = useState("");
  const [dataArr, setDataArr] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Todos updated, update item count in parent
    setItemsLeftCount(dataArr.length);
  }, [dataArr, setItemsLeftCount]);

  function getInputData(event) {
    setInputData(event.target.value);
  }

  function addTodo() {
    setDataArr((data) =>
      data.concat({
        id: nanoid(),
        todo: dataInput
      })
    );
  }

  function removeTodo(id) {
    setDataArr((data) => data.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ToDoBox isCreateBox getInputData={getInputData} addTodo={addTodo} />
      {dataArr.map((data) => (
        <ToDoBox key={data.id} data={data} removeTodo={removeTodo} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

ToDoBox

```
function ToDoBox({ addTodo, data, getInputData, isCreateBox, removeTodo }) {
  if (isCreateBox) {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          placeholder="Create a new todo..."
          onChange={getInputData}
          tabIndex={-1}
        />
        <span onClick={addTodo}>+</span>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{data.todo}</span>{" "}
        <span onClick={() => removeTodo(data.id)}>X</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit react-cannot-read-properties-of-null-of-ref-with-forwardref-and-useref]

Comment: Thank you! this is phenomenal and extremely helpful! I appreciate you working through this with me and providing feedback to the project's design as a whole

Comment: @Ford Yeah, it certainly seemed like a "Death by a thousand papercuts" sort of situation. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

- The parent `ref` can be modified using a function, this function is then passed down to its child. The child will then modify the parent's `ref` using this function

```
const MainComponent = () => {
  const myRef = useRef("old Ref");

  const changeRef = (val) => {
    myRef.current = val;
  };

  return <SubComponent changeRef={changeRef} />;
};

const SubComponent = ({ changeRef }) => {
  changeRef("new Ref");

  return <h1>Changed Parent's Ref!</h1>;
};
```

Comment: Implementing this I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: props.setPrevItemsLeftCountRef is not a function 

from this line of code: 
props.setPrevItemsLeftCountRef(props.itemsLeftCount);

Comment: Can you please show me how you implemented this?

Comment: its as you type it in your answer, but I can include it in my question for code blocks

Comment: Using useState at the app.js will make it re-render even if you updated it with a ref, so you have to consider changing the useState in app.js to a normal useRef

Comment: I don't see a problem in this block of code maybe it exist in another part in the code that you are not showing